# Junction Potential parameter in Keysight Genesys

Tags: diodes

In the Nonlinear Diode model in Keysight Genesys there is no forward bias voltage parameter. There is a "junction potential" (Vj) parameter, however. I've never seen or heard anyone use the term junction potential to describe a diode property though. Is it the same thing as forward bias voltage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `VJ` parameter is used by many SPICE-derived simulators for their diode models. It doesn't affect the I-V characteristics of the diode, but rather the capacitance characteristic.

The junction capacitance characteristic is given by

$$C_j(V)=\frac{C_j(0)}{\sqrt{1-V/V_j}}.$$

([source](http://www3.imperial.ac.uk/pls/portallive/docs/1/7292572.PDF))

The total capacitance of the diode is

$$C=C_j+C_d$$

with \$C_j\$ being dominant when the diode is reverse biased, and the diffusion capacitance \$C_d\$ being dominant when the diode is forward biased.

If you want to set the forward voltage of the diode, you need to look at the Shockley diode equation

$$I(V) = I_s \exp\left(\frac{V}{nV_T}-1\right)$$

and set the corresponding SPICE parameters `IS` and `N` (and possibly the series resistance `RS`) to achieve the forward voltage (and reverse leakage) to match your physical diode.